# What is the difference between [class] and [classes] tags? - synonym request

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

What is the difference between [class](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class) (25 questions) and [classes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classes) (19 questions) tags?

Neither of above have tag wiki, a handful of questions I randomly picked appear to use these as freely interchangeable.

---

#### update

Per feedback received so far, please merge mentioned tags, and make them synonyms.

Comment: Looks like they should be synonyms at the very least.

Comment: @YannisRizos thanks! While I have your attention, could you please take a look at ["static" tag cleanup](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5361/31260)? There seem to be a handful PHP questions worth re-tagging from static to something else

Comment: @gnat Not any more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question, and I agree with ChrisF's comment about creating the synonym.

FWIW, I just tried to create the synonym, but I don't have a tag score of 5 on either one.

Answer (score 5):

They definitely should be synonyms.

Honestly, I'm not a huge fan of synonyms if they could be merged and these could.